# yui3 create sugar method

Tags: javascript, yui3

How do I add sugar methods in yui3, so I can do something like this:

```
Y.one('#my_div').do_something();
```

where `.do_something()` is the sugar method I created.  I'd like to be able to package all of my code up, so I can load it like a widget.

Basically I want to recreate jQuery's `slideToggle()`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and created some for everyone to use: [here](https://github.com/imns/yui3-sugar)